# What is wrong? I'm getting this error. "This question body does not meet our quality standards"

Tags: support

Every time I try to post a question, I get this message.

What's wrong?

Comment: Without the question body that you were trying to post we can't help you much. You did read the link in the message right?

Comment: To add to Seth's comment, you can still [edit] your question and bring in more details, then it might get reopened so people can answer.